# user register from overflow

Tags: theming, users

In my register form email address description is overflow. I know that I have to change theme, but I would like to know where to theme it.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to simply edit the css in style.css of your activated theme. Go to `sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/style.css.`

Apply the css to the appropriate div of the field.

```
#user-register-form . description-field{
//css code here
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Your answer can fix my problem, it is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your themes output but maybe you could try to edit the style of

```
#user-register-form {

}
```

It would be helpful to see the website with the user-register-form.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by css.

You need to write your css in the theme that are being used to display this page, it could be the admin theme.

```
e.g.
#user-register-form .description{
width:400px;

}
```

So you can use hook_form_alter() in your custom module to insert your css.

```
function customModuleName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id=='user_register_form'){

drupal_add_css(/*css code */);
}
}
```